# How to display the assigned card to only specific user in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a system that only certain user can see the list of the projects. The list of the projects will be shown in user application when the projects have been assigned to them thru administration by using user's email. I am using flutter and google firebase

I tried to use If  else statement but I seem can't do it.
I have 2 model classes

User_model class

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Users{
  final String uid;
  Users({this.uid});
}

class UserModel{
  String uid;
  String email;
  String name;
  String employeeID;
  String phonenumber;
  String position;

  UserModel({this.uid, this.email, this.name, this.employeeID, this.phonenumber, this.position});

  //receiving data from server
  factory UserModel.fromMap(map){
    return UserModel(
      uid: map['uid'],
      email: map['email'],
      name: map['name'],
      employeeID: map['employeeID'],
      phonenumber: map['phonenumber'],
      position: map['position'],
    );
  }

  //sending data to our server
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
    return{
      'uid': uid,
      'email': email,
      'name' : name,
      'employeeID' : employeeID,
      'phonenumber' : phonenumber,
      'position' : position,
    };
  }
}

class UserProject{
  final String projectid;
  final String address;
  final String titleproject;
  final List<String> assignedmember ;

  UserProject({this.projectid, this.address, this.titleproject, this.assignedmember});
}
```

Project_model class

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Project{
  final String address;
  final String titleproject;
  final List<dynamic> assignedmember;

  Project({this.address, this.titleproject, this.assignedmember});

}
```

HomeScreen.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smartconstructionreport/data/project_model.dart';
import 'package:smartconstructionreport/data/user_model.dart';
import 'package:smartconstructionreport/screens/project_screen.dart';
import 'package:smartconstructionreport/theme.dart';
import 'package:smartconstructionreport/widget/ProjectCard.dart';
import 'package:smartconstructionreport/widget/menulist.dart';
import 'package:smartconstructionreport/service/database.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:smartconstructionreport/widget/projectlist.dart';

import 'FloorPlan.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  UserModel loggedInUser = UserModel();

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("user")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .get()
    .then((value){
      this.loggedInUser = UserModel.fromMap(value.data());
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<Project>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().projects,
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: menulist(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Image.asset('images/scdr logo.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: kDefaultPadding,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Hello ${loggedInUser.name},",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Have a great day ahead!',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 12,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Lets start working!',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 12,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Project Lists',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 18,
                ),
                ProjectList(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

ProjectList.dart
I tried to add If else statement to check if the project contains email assigned to the project. But it return null

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:smartconstructionreport/data/project_model.dart';
import 'package:smartconstructionreport/screens/project_screen.dart';

import 'ProjectCard.dart';

class ProjectList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProjectListState createState() => _ProjectListState();
}

class _ProjectListState extends State<ProjectList> {
  User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  Project projectmember = Project();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final projects = Provider.of<List<Project>>(context)  ?? [];

    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: projects.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (projectmember.assignedmember.contains(user.email)) {
          return ProjectCard(project: projects[index],
            press: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ProjectScreen(),
              ));
            },
          );
        };
        }
    );
  }
}
```

ProjectCard.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smartconstructionreport/data/project_model.dart';
import 'package:smartconstructionreport/theme.dart';

class ProjectCard extends StatelessWidget {

  final Function press;
  final Project project;
  ProjectCard({this.project, this.press});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: press,
      child: Card(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
        ),
        elevation: 10,
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 15.0, 5.0, 10.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: Text(
                    project.titleproject,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Divider(color: Colors.black),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0),
              child: Text(
                project.address,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    TextButton.icon(
                        onPressed: (){},
                        icon: Icon(Icons.person,
                          color: kPrimaryColor,) ,
                        label: Text('Project Manager')),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(width:50),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    TextButton.icon(
                        onPressed: (){},
                        icon: Icon(Icons.location_pin,
                          color: kPrimaryColor,) ,
                        label: Text('MAP')),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The method 'contains' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: contains("rashid@fyp.com")
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: cna u show where u are using this contains("rashid@fyp.com") in the code...

Comment: it is from the cloud firestore, the data of email ("rashid2@fyp,com") is already in the database.

Comment: here is saying the contains was called on null which mean the list you are calling is null, so you have to check for null. before getting the value.

Comment: You defined `Project projectmember = Project();` like this, which will make all the properties (`address`, `titleproject`, `assignedmember`) null. `projectmember.assignedmember.contains()` will try to call contains() on null, and it will throw that error. So, give values to the properties of `projectmember`.

Comment: @PeterO. can you show me how to give values to the properties?

Comment: @Adila : Yes, usually like this: `Project projectmember = Project(address: 'Nigeria', titleproject: 'teaching', assignedmember: 'rashid2@fyp.com');`. Here, address is 'Nigeria' and the rest. `projectmember.assignedmember.contains('rashid2@fyp.com')` returns true. If you add `factory Project.fromMap(map)` to your `Project` class, then you can get the projectmember data from Firestore and do something like this: `Project projectmember = Project.fromMap(projectmemberData.data());`